# Windows Failover cluster error on (SQL Server 2012 Always On)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, alwayson

We have configured AG in SQL Server 2012. AG has 3 nodes, one node (for example server 1) is primary replica with manual failover, and one node (server 2) is configured for secondary replica with automatic failover, one node(server 3) is configured for secondary replica with automatic failover.

After that when upgrade network card we tried to change the node, one node (for example server 3) is primary replica with automatic failover, and one node (server 2) is configured for secondary replica with automatic failover, one node (server 1) is configured for secondary replica with manual failover. The AG environment failed - the databases in AG did not shown and Windows Cluster event showing Error 1069 and 1205.

Below mention the details of AG DashBoard:

1. Current configuration :

   ```
   SERVERS     FAILOVER MODE   REPLICA
   ---------------------------------------
   Server-1    Manual          Primary
   Server-2    Automatic       Secondary
   Server-3    Automatic       Secondary
   ```
2. We tried to change node :

   ```
   SERVERS     FAILOVER MODE   REPLICA
   ---------------------------------------
   Server-1    Manual          Secondary
   Server-2    Automatic       Secondary
   Server-3    Automatic       Primary
   ```

Comment: Simply a followup to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263791/windows-fail-over-cluster-error-on-sql-server-2012-always-on) with more detail. But still off-topic for SO. A better fit is dba.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.